# Javascript and jQuery hide and show not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide and show the contact form (using display:"none" and display:"block") when clicking the button "click me!". I've tried multiple javascript and jquery examples but none of them seem to work for me. It would be nice if the form would slide in and out under the click me button.

Can someone help me?

Visit this link to see my code http://jsfiddle.net/jm2o73f2/9/

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("hidden");
    x.style.
}
```

```css
body, img, ul, li, div, input, textarea {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    background:#CCC;
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom:-20px;
}
#footer img {
    cursor:pointer;   
}
#footer ul {
    list-style:none;
    width:250px;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#footer #contact {
    width:400px;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    background:white;
    text-align:left;
}
#footer #contact textarea {
    width:250px;
    resize:none;
}
#footer #contact input {
    width:250px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
#footer #contact input[type="submit"] {
   width:100px; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="footer">
        <div id="contact">
            <ul><li>Vragen? Stuur ons gerust een email.</li><li><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button></li></ul>
            <div id="hidden">
            <ul><li><input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" /></li><li><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></li><li><textarea  name="condolatie" id="condolatie" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></li><li><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Verzend" /></li></ul></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post your code here please?

Comment: I would also be helpful a link to the site.

Comment: The site isn't uploaded yet. This is my code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jm2o73f2/9/ Hope this helps.

Comment: In JavaScript.... line 3....:
    x.style.

Comment: make sure you include the code before your button and to finish the line of code: display = 'none' (or block) http://jsfiddle.net/jm2o73f2/10/

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! I've found some working solutions thanks to you guys. Sorry for my beginner mistakes, I still have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution without seeing your code would be:

```
$(function(){
    $('.revealButton').click(function(){
        $('.hiddenDiv').toggle();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, however, once your code is here I will update this answer :)

**UPDATE**

Here is a working jQuery version for you: ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davcpas123/jm2o73f2/13/)***

```
$(function () {
    $('.revealButton').click(function () {
        $('#hidden').toggle();
    });
});
```

Also, on your button remove `onClick="myFunction()"` and add `class="revealButton"`.

and that's it.

**UPDATE 2**

If you would like a slide animation (as mentioned in the comments) use this: ***[jsFiddleUpdate](http://jsfiddle.net/davcpas123/jm2o73f2/16/)***

```
$(function () {
    $('.revealButton').click(function () {
        $('#hidden').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Kenkey if you want with a slide animation you can use `.slideToggle()` instead of `.toggle()`. I noticed you mentioned that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code in head or before the end of body. You then need to check if the element is hidden or not the do the appropriate action

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hidden").style;
  x.display === 'none' ? x.display = 'block' : x.display = 'none';
  // is display none ? set to block else set to none
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hidden").style;
  x.display === 'none' ? x.display = 'block' : x.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body, img, ul, li, div, input, textarea {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    background:#CCC;
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom:-20px;
}
#footer img {
    cursor:pointer;   
}
#footer ul {
    list-style:none;
    width:250px;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#footer #contact {
    width:400px;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    background:white;
    text-align:left;
}
#footer #contact textarea {
    width:250px;
    resize:none;
}
#footer #contact input {
    width:250px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
#footer #contact input[type="submit"] {
   width:100px; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="contact">
    <ul>
      <li>Vragen? Stuur ons gerust een email.</li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="hidden">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <textarea name="condolatie" id="condolatie" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Verzend" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you should use:

```
$("#hidden.isHidden").show().removeClass("isHidden");
```

to show your element from its ID "hidden", and that to hide it:

```
$("#hidden").hide().addClass("isHidden");
```

**EDIT:**

you could also use this code to detect if your element is hidden:

```
if ($("#hidden").is(':hidden')) { ... }
```

and to test if it is displayed:

```
if ($("#hidden").is(':visible')) { ... }
```